# Flutter count number of page view and show it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to implement the number of views feature in my application with flutter.

The feature is the same as StackOverflow question view counter: it's persisted.

I was thinking of firebase analytics but I think it's not free to get data from there

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firebase Analytics is free https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ "unlimited reporting for up to 500 distinct events". https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics

Comment: yes, it's free but when you try to return data it's not free, the way I found to return analytics data is to use BigQuery which is in the BLAZE plan. https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: You can export the analytics reports as CSV from the Firebase console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is correct but you should know it's not free.
The way I found to return analytics data is to use BigQuery which is in the BLAZE plan so I think you have to pay to get data from firebase analytics

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the number of views in my recent app i used Firestore, which is Firebase's Database. Initialize the views as zero in your database and then write a function to increment the view every time the user views it.

How do you determine if the user viewed it?
Now that entirely depends on your application.

Comment: this what I'll finally do but do you know any other way to track the user that views the page as firebase analytics does?

Comment: you can probably add the function to increment the view in the initState function of that particular widget. So when the widget builds the view is incremented. Although there might be other options using firebase analytics, check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31KpJXqCayo

Answer (score 1):

There is a short way instead if you just want to capture number of visitors on your webapp

I created a collection called "Visits" in firestore and generated auto id inside which I added a field called "count". That's it! Now you just have to call this method in your first screen's init method :

```
updateCounter() async {
final cRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('VISITS');
await cRef
    .doc("mS9fCXjvkpREt8LvanSb")
    .set({"count": FieldValue.increment(1)}, SetOptions(merge: true));
}
```