# How to count page view in flutter when the user visits the page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering about How to **count page view** in flutter on each time the user visit the page?

should I use something like [Shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store the value and updating it in the `initState()`?

I've seen similar topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776268/flutter-count-number-of-page-view-and-show-it) but none get me a clear idea about how to achieve that.

Comment: you need to store the page count in firebase or any database(api) ,or text file .sharepreference act as browser cache

Comment: Thanks @lava for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using google analytics or firebase analytics.
You can follow this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/overview/
and add this in your initState

```
await FirebaseAnalytics.instance
  .setCurrentScreen(
    screenName: 'Products'
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, Can I get the value from **Firebase** again for free? because I've seen some people here saying that I have to have a premium Firebase plan!

Comment: I am not sure about that. In that case you can store counter value in local database like sqlite or hive and when in need you can retrieve it.

Comment: I think this is a better way to achieve this, Thanks a lots.